# javascript: wait for a return

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this problem.
I have a function for example called functionA() that needs the results from another function called functionB().

```
var globalVar="";
function functionA(){
    //...
    functionB();
    //here i have to use the global variable (that is empty because functionB isn't finished)
}
function functionB(){
    //ajax request
    globalVar=ajaxRequest.responseText;
}
```

How can I do to let the functionB finish befor continue with the execution of functionA?
Thanks!

This is the code:

```
var ingredientiEsistenti="";
function ShowInserisciCommerciale() {
    getElementiEsistenti();
    JSON.parse(ingredientiEsistenti);
}

function getElementiEsistenti(){

// prendo gli ingredienti esistenti.
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/Ingredienti";
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);
xmlHttp.send(null);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) // COMPLETED
    {
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) // SUCCESSFUL
        {
            ingredientiEsistenti = xmlHttp.responseText;
        } else {

            alert("An error occurred while communicating with login server.");
        }
    }
};
}
```

Comment: If you have direct control over the XMLHttpRequest object you can set it to not be an asynchronous call. Otherwise I would consult the library you use to make ajax calls to turn it into a synchronous call or modify the code below `functionB()` to be a callback to the async `functionB()` call.

Comment: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets:_Synchronous_AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got one of many options, that don't require an *evil* global variable:

- Move the code you want to see executed to the `onreadystatechange` callback of the ajax request, that way, it won't get executed until you received a response
- Redefine `functionA`, so that it takes a parameter that allows you to skip the first bit:
- Make the request synchronous, not recommended, though
- use a timeout/interval to check the readystate of the request manually (brute-force, not recommended either)
- Perhaps there is some worker trickery that could do the trick, too, in your particular case

---

```
function functionA(skipDown)
{
    skipDown = skipDown || false;
    if (skipDown === false)
    {
        //doStuff
        return functionB();//<-- call functionA(true); from the readystatechange callback
    }
    //this code will only be called if skipDown was passed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have a sleep/wait in JavaScript when the call is asynchronous. You need to use a callback pattern to make this action occur.

It is possible to make an XMLHttpRequest synchronous, but that can lead to other problems. It can hang the browser as it blocks all other actions from happening. So if you want to show a loading animation, it most likely will not execute.

Comment: Except that you can tell your XHR to be synchronous

Comment: @Marty - pass false to the open function for the request object. ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, false);

Comment: @Marty did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your AJAX request synchronous. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Last parameter makes it not asnychronous
request.open('GET', 'http://www.mozilla.org/', false); 
request.send(null);
// Won't get here until the network call finishes
if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

However, that will block the UI while waiting for the server to respond, which is almost never what you want. In that case, you should use a callback to process results.

Here's an example using a callback without relying on a global variable. You should always run away from those

```
function ShowInserisciCommerciale(  ) {
    getElementiEsistenti(function(responseText) {
        JSON.parse(responseText);
    });
}

function getElementiEsistenti(successCallback){
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/Ingredienti";
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) // COMPLETED
        {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) // SUCCESSFUL
            {
                successCallback(xmlHttp.responseText); 

            } else {

                alert("An error occurred while communicating with login server.");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: it's your `functionB`? Let me put in an example with your code